# Is there any software available to input text by speaking via microphone?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-to-speech, speech-recognition

Is there any good 'Speech to Text' application available for Ubuntu?

I have tried to find something in Software Center but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called **simon** that can be installed through the software center.

From the Simon description:

Simon is an open-source speech recognition program and replaces the mouse and keyboard.  It is in development for physically disabled people and seniors to give them the possibility to chat, to write e-mails, to surf the internet, to do internet-banking and much more. It is designed to be very flexible and allows customization for any application where speech recognition is needed.

Comment: I think simon is deprecated