# Offline speech to text across all apps

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm looking for an offline speech recognition software that would work for all Linux apps. The ideal solution would be just like the VS Code Speech extension:

1. Hold a shortcut
2. Speak
3. Release shortcut
4. Text is inserted at caret position

The other answers I saw here are old, referring to now unsupported packages (or online for the google one):

- [Is there any software available to input text by speaking via microphone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010476/is-there-any-software-available-to-input-text-by-speaking-via-microphone)
- [Can I dictate to the Linux desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802193/can-i-dictate-to-the-linux-desktop)
- [What's the best speech recognition software for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438489/whats-the-best-speech-recognition-software-for-ubuntu)